# JPA Hibernate. Select : ORDER clause depending on the value of a column

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am running into an issue.

I search for several hours but did not find any anwers.

What I want to do is a sql select, in which the ORDER clause depends on the value of a column (so it changes for every tuples).

I managed to do it via HQL with something like that :

```
SELECT NEW myDTO(m.id, m.name, " + calculDistance + " AS distance) FROM Table m GROUP BY m.mercId ORDER BY distance ASC
```

With calculDistance depending of m.latitude and m.longitude

This works fine.
However, my request is much more complicated than that and for reading, update and such reasons, I'd like to do it directly with JPA.

Do you know if this is possible?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

Here is the part of my table structure (I put only the needed columns):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "td_merchant")
@XmlRootElement
@SequenceGenerator(name = "td_merchant_id_seq", sequenceName = "td_merchant_id_seq")
public class Merchant implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "td_merchant_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "merc_id")
private Integer mercId;

@Column(name = "merc_name")
private String mercName;

@Column(name = "merc_latitude")
private Double mercLatitude;
@Column(name = "merc_longitude")
private Double mercLongitude;

...
}
```

Comment: Can use provide table structures ?

Comment: Ok just edit my question with a part of the structure

Comment: @Boris, how would you like to change the ORDER clause?

Comment: @zxcf, what do you mean? I can't change this order clause unfortunately

Comment: @Boris I just don't understand what you asking about. I cannot understand phrase `What I want to do is a sql select, in which the ORDER clause depends on the value of a column (so it changes for every tuples).`

Comment: My order by is for example    ORDER BY (m.mercLatitude + m.mercLongitude)   So it depends on the columns. And i'd like to do that not by hql but with jpa

Answer (score 0):

```
I also faced same issue, i wrote one function which was taking input for order by as well as asc and desc seq.

public List<CompanyName> loadAllCompanies(CompanySortField sortField, boolean ascending) {

    String queryString = "select new com.Company(u.name, u.surname, " +
            " country.name, country.population, " +
            " city.name) from Company u left join u.city as city left join u.country as country " +
            " order by " + sortField.getField() + (ascending ? " asc " : " desc ");
    return entityManager.createQuery(queryString).getResultList();
}
```

You can try in this way, only thing is you need to fire another query to find out company sort field.